# Way to handle event on changes to registry? : Long running EventWaitHandle?

Tags: c#, windows-services, registry

I have a Windows service that constantly runs and has a config class that gets loaded from the registry. I have a separate "Settings" application that sets these registry files.
What I need is a way to let my service know that the settings have changed, and to reload the config class.

My first thought was an EventWaitHandle that the "Settings" application could `Set()` once the user saves the settings. My service would start a separate thread in the `OnStart()` that has nothing but

```
while(true)
{
    myWaitEventHandler.WaitOne();
    ReloadConfig();
}
```

Is this a good solution? Is it bad to have an EventWaitHandle "waiting" 24/7?

Comment: It doesn't get tired.  Not the greatest use of a system resource, don't you have other things to wait on?  Like the stop request and whatever thing you do in the service?  Then use WaitAny().

Comment: Not yet I don't have anything else to wait on, but it may come up in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody is wondering, I've had this running for a couple days now, and haven't noticed any negative effects.